# Tensorflow get all variables in scope

Tags: tensorflow

I have some variables created within a certain scope like this:

```
with tf.variable_scope("my_scope"):
  createSomeVariables()
  ...
```

I then want to get the list of all the variables in "my_scope" so I can pass it to an optimizer. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I think you want [tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='my_scope')](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_collection).  This will get all variables in a scope.

To pass to an optimizer you do not want *all* variables you would just want the trainable variables.  Those are also kept in a default collection, which is `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`.

Comment: `tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES` is deprecated in v0.12 (as I learned from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40918792/1827383). Use `tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES` instead.

Comment: do you have have to create an op out of that and then run it in a session? It seems the code is incomplete, do you mind making it self contained?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How about this situation: there are two sub scopes `tf.variable_scope(1st)`  and `tf.variable_scope(2nd)` inside a scope `tf.variable_scope(main)`  and I want to get two lists of scopes `1st` and `2nd` so as to optimize separately.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong (tested in tensorflow 1.4). 

tf.get_collection gets by NAME scope, and not by VARIABLE scope. You could have a bunch of variables declared under variable_scope("foo"), and tf.get_collection(..,"foo") would return nothing.

Comment: One might want to detect the scope name automatically:
`tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope=tf.get_variable_scope().name)`

Answer (score 16):

User correctly pointed out that you need [`tf.get_collection()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_collection). I will just give a simple example how to do this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.name_scope('some_scope1'):
    a = tf.Variable(1, 'a')
    b = tf.Variable(2, 'b')
    c = tf.Variable(3, 'c')

with tf.name_scope('some_scope2'):
    d = tf.Variable(4, 'd')
    e = tf.Variable(5, 'e')
    f = tf.Variable(6, 'f')

h = tf.Variable(8, 'h')

for i in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='some_scope'):
    print i   # i.name if you want just a name
```

Notice that you can provide any of the [graphKeys](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys) and scope is a regular expression:

> scope: (Optional.) If supplied, the resulting list is filtered to
>   include only items whose name attribute matches using re.match. Items
>   without a name attribute are never returned if a scope is supplied and
>   the choice or re.match means that a scope without special tokens
>   filters by prefix.

So if you will pass 'some_scope' you will get 6 variables.

Comment: what if I then wanted to put all other variables in a separate collection. For example, GLOBAL_VARIABLES contains a through h, and 'some_scope' ends up with a through f, but then I want to have a second operation that just gets anything that isn't in my other collection (without using the regex)

Comment: How would you use this paired with session.run() to get the list of variables ?