# Tensorflow: tf.get_collection Not Returning Variables in Scope

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to get all the variables in a variable scope, as is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533723/tensorflow-get-all-variables-in-scope). However, the line `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='my_scope')` is returning an empty list even though there are variables in that scope.

Here's some example code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope('my_scope'):
    a = tf.Variable(0)
print tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='my_scope')
```

which prints `[]`.

How can I get the variables declared in `'my_scope'`?

Comment: as a warning to future readers, note that `name_scope` and `variable_scope` are not the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES` collection name has been deprecated since TensorFlow 0.12. Using `tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES` will give the expected result:

```
with tf.variable_scope('my_scope'):
    a = tf.Variable(0)
print tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='my_scope')
# ==> '[<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7f33f67ebbd0>]'
```

Comment: Some deprecation message during running would be nice : )

Comment: for me that is still not working. Do I need to pass the graph somewhere or something like that?

Comment: I tried using the graph object itself directly and didn't work: `graph.get_collection(name='scope_name')`. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: @CharlieParker The `tf.get_collection()` method assumes that everything is in a single default graph (i.e. the graph returned by `tf.get_default_graph()`).  If you have multiple graph objects, and the graph of interest is called `g`, you can use [`g.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='my_scope')`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_collection) instead. However, if that doesn't work, you might have the wrong `tf.Graph` object. It would probably be easiest to address in a separate question with more of the code.

Comment: ok never mind. The error seems to be my confusion of `variable_scope` vs `name_scope`. I read the answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919020/whats-the-difference-of-name-scope-and-a-variable-scope-in-tensorflow , but it still doesn't make sense to me why there are two types of name scoping (seems really annoying).