# Export weights of neural network using tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I wrote neural-network using tensorflow tools. 
everything working and now I want to export the final weights of my neural network to make a single prediction method. 
How can I do this?

Comment: https://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/checkpointing-and-reusing-tensorflow-models/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to save your model at the end of training by using the [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) class.

While initializing the `Saver` object, you will need to pass a list of all the variables you wish to save. The best part is that you can use these saved variables in a different computation graph!

Create a `Saver` object by using,

```
# Assume you want to save 2 variables `v1` and `v2`
saver = tf.train.Saver([v1, v2])
```

Save your variables by using the [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/client.html#Session) object,

```
saver.save(sess, 'filename');
```

Of course, you can add additional details like `global_step`.

You can restore the variables in the future by using the `restore()` function. The restored variables will be initialized to these values automatically.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain raw data of the parameters? I want to run a tensorflow-trained-model on anther platform, how can I do that?

Comment: You can get the final value of the weights using `sess.run(weights)` and export them to a numpy array for instance

Comment: That's what I need. Another problem: I used `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell` in the net, how can I access the weight/bias of an `LSTMCell` object?

Comment: If you try to use `tf.all_variables()`, you will see the names of the weight and bias of the `LSTMCell`. You can improve this search by searching for variables under the `LSTMCell` scope only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533723/tensorflow-get-all-variables-in-scope

Comment: Thank you @martianwars . You just saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is the standard way to save/restore session snapshot. However, if you want to export your network as a single binary file for further use with other tensorflow tools, you'll need to perform few more steps.

First, [freeze the graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/tool_developers/index.html#freezing). TF provides the corresponding tool. I use it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# The script combines graph definition and trained weights into
# a single binary protobuf with constant holders for the weights.
# The resulting graph is suitable for the processing with other tools.


TF_HOME=~/tensorflow/

if [ $# -lt 4 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 graph_def snapshot output_nodes output.pb"
    exit 0
fi

proto=$1
snapshot=$2
out_nodes=$3
out=$4

$TF_HOME/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph --input_graph=$proto \
    --input_checkpoint=$snapshot \
    --output_graph=$out \
    --output_node_names=$out_nodes
```

Having done that, you can [optimize it for inference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py), or use [any other tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/tools).

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to access weights and biases of your neural net you can use the `get_weights()` method from `tf.keras.layers.Layer`

```
#params vector includes weights and biases
params = your_model.get_weights()
```