# TensorFlow: Understanding the `collections` argument in tf.summary.scalar

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am working with TensorBoard, specifically `tf.summary.scalar`. In the [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/summary.md#tfsummaryscalarname-tensor-collectionsnone-scalar) it has an arugment `collections=None`, which is described as:

> `collections`: Optional list of graph collections keys. The new summary op is added to these collections. Defaults to `[GraphKeys.SUMMARIES]`.

I don't understand this description, and what `collections` is used for. Can someone please explain this to me, and perhaps point me towards a good example use-case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a hidden gem! You can provide it a list of strings of your choice that label the summary node, e.g.

```
tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', p_lr, collections=['train'])
tf.summary.scalar('loss', t_loss, collections=['train', 'test'])
```

and then fetch the summaries by their label, e.g. like so:

```
s_training = tf.summary.merge_all('train')
s_test = tf.summary.merge_all('test')
```

I'm doing it like that because I often want to log extra information during the validation phase; in the above example, I don't have to provide a value for the learning rate placeholder `p_lr` when evaluating (and writing) the accuracy, for example - or anything really that the inference part of the graph relies on.

Providing (only) custom categories also has the nice side effect of hiding the node from `Supervisor`, for example. If you really want to have control over when exactly you write a summary (e.g. using `sv.summary_computed()` in case of `Supervisor`), that's an easy way to go.

Comment: Great description! `collection`s can be used more generally when ever you want to access all of something that are spread out all over e.g. if you want all biases in a graph this could be used. Discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533723/tensorflow-get-all-variables-in-scope). See `get_collection` documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework/#get_collection).