# Unnamed Op not showing in list_tensors command during debug session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have these two unnamed op tensors `logits` and `outputs` under a variable scope, but the `lt` command isn't listing these two tensors under the op 'MatMul' and 'Softmax' during the `tfdbg` session after a test run on a checkpoint. Here is a snapshot of the code:

```
with tf.variable_scope(scope):
    d_inputs = dropout(inputs, keep_prob=keep_prob, is_train=is_train)
    d_memory = dropout(memory, keep_prob=keep_prob, is_train=is_train)
    JX = tf.shape(inputs)[1]

    with tf.variable_scope("attention"):
        inputs_ = tf.nn.relu(dense(d_inputs, hidden, use_bias=False, scope="inputs"))
        memory_ = tf.nn.relu(dense(d_memory, hidden, use_bias=False, scope="memory"))
        outputs = tf.matmul(inputs_, tf.transpose(memory_, [0, 2, 1])) / (hidden ** 0.5)
        mask = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(mask, axis=1), [1, JX, 1])
        # The tensor down below 
        logits = tf.nn.softmax(softmax_mask(outputs, mask))
        # And the tensor down below here as well
        outputs = tf.matmul(logits, memory)
        res = tf.concat([inputs, outputs], axis=2)
```

What can I do to retrieve these variables for testing purposes on `tfdbg`?
For alternative purposes, can I retrieve them using the normal tensorflow session by using `tf.add_to_collection(op_name, tensor)` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639260/retrieving-an-unnamed-variable-in-tensorflow)?

Comment: @engineero can you look into this? I've linked your answer in this question for a tensorflow issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no such thing as "unnamed tensor". If you don't provide a name for an op, it will use a default name. The output tensors will usually be named using the operation's OpDef spec. If there is a single output, it can be named using just the op name. If the name is already taken, it will be made unique by appending _N to it.

You should see all tensors with plain `lt` command. Are you giving some options to it?

For the second question, tensorflow collections are basically just dictionaries that can be saved and restored "automatically". If you want to get have a persistent fixed name for some tensor, you can certainly save it in a collection and retrieve it after restoring from a checkpoint.